# rt.jar / Key.Adapter.class

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, rt.jar

Googling a lot, I found nothing about the problem with this specific class (`Key.Adapter.class`), but there are a lot of topics about `rt.jar` of course, and I tried so many things to correct it, I tried to set the location of rt.jar and installed the plugin Java Source Attacher (didn't work). I reinstalled Eclipse as well, but the error still occurs:

[image: Error Screenshot]

What's strange about this is that I didn't make any change at anything related to the library (if I did, that was not intentional). I was just moving some things but nothing related to the libraries. The console returns NullPointerException at line 190:

```
name2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

                int key = arg0.getKeyCode();

                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {

                    //Custom button text
                    Object[] options = {"Sim",
                                        "Não"};

                        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame1,
                        "Deseja sair do jogo?",
                        "Mensagem",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        options,
                        options[1]);

                        if (choice == 0) {

                            System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        }

        );
```

To make a new project will be that way as well. And the Window Designer / Run doesn't work as well.

Is there another possibility to make `rt.jar` useful again?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.Main.<init>(Main.java:191)
    at view.Main$1.run(Main.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You need better details in your question. For example, you say line 190, but you don't provide a stack trace or the actual line numbers of the code you've added. Currently, there's no way to answer your question effectively.

Comment: The console shows this message as well: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)... Despite the code I have posted, I don't think the code is bugged because that was working fine before, I really think that the rt.jar is the source of the problem...

Comment: Still not enough. You should edit your original question to contain the entire stack trace and indicate which line of code the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: Well, I have edited the post, I didn't realize that was more lines on the console... sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize.

Comment: Do you have any other Java installations available that you can use? I would switch to any other installation, so you can at least rule that out.

Comment: I don't have... I have changed some things on the code, like links of images and variable names... That was my error, the program is running ok now. But the rt.jar still seems to be with problem in KeyAdapter.class and AccessController.class... these 2 want the source attached...

Comment: Provide source of view.Main and mark 191 there exlicitly, via comment. Then request reopen.